# how can i use the function CREATE in soap webservice in Navision in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, navision

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477097%28v=nav.70%29.aspx) you can see documentation. It is in C# . I tried to make a working example using PHP. I managed to execute the **Read & ReadMultiple** functions in PHP. This is my try:

```
   require ("./NTLMSoapClient.php");
    $client = new NTLMSoapClient(null, array(
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'trace' => true,
        'location' => "http://83.166.204.26:7147/TEST/WS/Harmont%20Blaine_TEST/Page/WebItem",
        'uri' => "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/webitem",

    ));
    $client->user = "xxxxxx";
    $client->password = "xxxxxxxxx";
 try{

    $resp = $client->Create(new SoapVar('555554', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'ns1:No' ));
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";
}catch(SoapFault $sf){
    //echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($sf); 
    print '</pre>'; 
}
print '<pre>';var_dump($resp);  print '</pre>';
```

It returns me **NULL** for some reason. Any idea why is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS is the solution :

```
$resp = $client->Create(new SoapVar('5555195', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'ns1:WebItem' ));
```

I have to change the **No** to **WebItem**

see here:

```
<xsd:element name="Create">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="WebItem" type="tns:WebItem"/></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Freddy Kristiansen did a wonderful series of blog posts with detailed explanation how to connect to Nav web services from different environments.

First part is here:
[Connecting to NAV Web Services from …](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk/archive/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from.aspx)

The second part:
[Connecting to NAV Web Services from PHP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk/archive/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-php.aspx)

Client can receive NULL response for several reasons. First of them - client application is unable to authenticate on the web service. This can happen if the server side uses SPNEGO protocol instead of NTLM. You need to set the key "ServicesUseNTLMAuthentication" in CustomSettings.config, as Freddy described in the first of his posts.

If you can read data from the service, but cannot create a record, this means that the request successfully passes authentication, and the problem is likely in the SOAP message format.

This is what Nav expects to receive in Create request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <Create xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/customer">
            <Customer>
                <No>555554</No>
                <Name>NewCustomer</Name>
            </Customer>
        </Create>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

To achieve this result, you could replace standard HTTP stream wrapper with NTLMStream wrapper (see the post "Connecting to NAV web services from PHP" above.

Now, this is all you need to do to read a customer record:

```
$client = new NTLMSoapClient("http://192.168.0.101:7047/DynamicsNAV71/WS/".rawurlencode($company)."/Page/Customer");
$resp = $client -> Read(array('No' => '10000'));
```

Creating new records becomes much easier as well:

```
$client = new NTLMSoapClient("http://192.168.0.101:7047/DynamicsNAV71/WS/".rawurlencode($company)."/Page/Customer");

class CustomerWrapper
{
    public $Customer;
}

$cw = new CustomerWrapper;
$cw -> Customer -> No = "555554";
$cw -> Customer -> Name = "NewCustomerName";
$cw -> Customer -> E_Mail = "john.doe@cronuscorp.net";
$resp = $client -> Create($customer);
```

Comment: I used this link: http://code.google.com/p/php-ews/source/browse/NTLMSoapClient.php. I managed to read data , but not to create data.

Comment: I don't understand where I have to add this line of code: <add key="WebServicesUseNTLMAuthentication" value="true"></add> . I don't have access to server , just to client